# Is it possible to use Feign Client on Spring Boot without creating any Model Classes ? Since the client API returns quite a complex JSON Object

Tags: json, spring-boot, feign

Is it possible to use Feign Client on Spring boot, to call some 3rd party API, and it returns quite a huge JSON object that include different types of object and array. Do I have to create a model class that reflect every single variable in that JSON object ? I think it's quite a problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Feign without a response model defined.

For example you can use the `feign.Response` class to deal with the plain HTTP response.